# No cached version of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.10 available for offline mode

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I am using android studio 4.0 and whenever i create a new project offline(without access to internet) it gives me this error and I haven't access to internet most of times. I tried toggling offline mode button and everything but again I need to have access to internet for complete build. Is there any solution to this or you need to have access to internet when build you project?
I used to use Java for android app development and could build project offline too. but I have migrated to Kotlin and this give me this error. Please, answer!!

Answer (score 0):

I tried this. I disabled offline mode. You might get this error "Unknown host 'jcenter.bintray.com'" when you build. To handle this error, try the below steps.

Go to project >> build.gradle. Add the below into your projects.

> android{ allprojects {
> repositories {  google()
> jcenter()
> maven {url"https://jitpack.io"} }}